# Bash loop and function parameter expansion

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a trivial for loop in a bash script which is not working and I cannot see what is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
function deleteOut {

for index in {0..$1}
do
    echo "/bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_${index}.log"
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_${index}.log
done
}
```

and called it using

> deleteOut 5

I was expecting a loop like

```
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_0.log
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_1.log
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_2.log
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_3.log
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_4.log
    /bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_5.log
```

Instead I got

```
/bin/rm -rf ./OUT/Message_{0..5}.log
```

I've solved the problem doing something like this instead

```
find ./OUT -name "Message_*.log" | xargs /bin/rm
```

but this is not the point. Why my first approach didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` or subshell

Brace expansion comes *before* variable expansion

```
 for index in $(eval "echo {0..$q}")
 do 
     echo $index
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq`, which is in general safer than `eval`:

```
for index in $(seq $1)
```

Or even faster [without any external program](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D):

```
for ((index=1; index<=$1; index++))
```

Comment: The second command would be correct if index=0. The first command is not usable because the range was 0..$1 and seq (as far as I know) start with 1. But actually you are answering how to loop over the files whereas my question is about the parameter expansion in the range. The answer from "sehe" is the correct one: "Brace expansion comes before variable expansion" (I didn't know it). Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: The link explains the expansion issue and links to more information.